# How have the "in + [adjective]" type expressions, such as "in general", "in common" and "in private", come into use?

Tags: idioms, prepositions

How have "in + [adjective]" type expressions, such as "in general", "in common" and "in private", come into use?  I'm puzzled by these expressions, because I understand that a preposition is usually followed by a noun phrase. Is it the case that there used to be a noun after the adjective, for example "in general **cases**", and later it was dropped?

Comment: Other examples are _in brief_, _in short_, _in vain_ and _in full_. Most of these are close synonyms of adverbs (generally / privately / vainly), though 'commonly' is rarely used for 'in common'. Similarly, _of late_ means 'lately', _at first_ 'firstly', _for sure / certain_ 'certainly'.

Comment: Etymoline says [*in vain*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vain)  is from "c. 1300, after Latin *in vanum*" ; and [*in general*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=general) is from late 1300s. French *en général* is attested c. 1270 [(CNRTL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral). So Latin, French, Latin via French, may have been the source of various *in + [adj.]* English phrases. Others may have been fashioned after *in vain, in general*.

Answer (score 1):

The examples that you give can all be extended thus:

- in general *terms*
- in common *with each other*
- in private *circumstances*

The examples offered by Edwin Ashforth in his comment can also be easily handled in this way. Of these, "in vain" probably requires explanation: it appears to have come from French "dans une vaine tentative," literally  "in a vain attempt." (The Latin for "empty" or "without substance" is "vanus.")